# Does dm-crypt compatible with btrfs on dm-smr drives?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I want to setup a encrypted drive using btrfs on a DM-SMR hard drive. and I am concerning about dm-crypt don't expose ZNS interface to btrfs.

I tried search but only get these:

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26900705

```
Nitpick: the device mapper zoned-device support isn't built on top of the device mapper encrypted-device support; both dm-crypt and dm-zoned are independent device mapper targets.
This is native support for btrfs-on-SMR, without the dm-zoned layer in between. DM-zoned is meant for filesystems who are zone-unaware, and it works by batching writes and redirecting blocks into appropriate areas. Having the filesystem allocator be aware of the underlying device's zones allows for more efficient/performant use of the zones.
```

So does dm-crypt work well with btrfs on DM-SMR?